# Logging from validator class

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a simple class as follows used in web API. As you can see it has a validator applied via attribute

```
[CustomerNameValidator]
public class Customer
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

Validator class looks like following

```
public class CustomerNameValidatorAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        Customer customer = (Customer)validationContext.ObjectInstance;

        if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(customer.CustomerName))
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Invalid customer Name");
        }


        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

I want to add some logging in the IsValid method. I am using logging in other places that is setup using Startup class as follows.

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();


    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();
    loggerFactory.AddNLog();
}
```

How can logger could be used in the validation attribute class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ValidationContext` is [populated](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/760c8f38678118734399c58c2dac981ea6e47046/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations/Internal/ValidatableObjectAdapter.cs#L34) with the `RequestServices` property of the `HttpContext` (an `IServiceProvider` instance). This means you can resolve services from it using the [`GetService` method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/ValidationContext.cs,276) on `ValidationContext`.

For example:

```
var logger = (ILogger<CustomerNameValidatorAttribute>)validationContext.GetService(typeof(ILogger<CustomerNameValidatorAttribute>));
```

Comment: If you add `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;`, you can use `var logger = validationContext.GetService<ILogger<CustomerNameValidatorAttribute>>();` without casting